# Adding table rows and column dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add rows and columns to a table using user input values to determine the number of rows and columns dynamically using jQuery. Below is my code which actually adds rows and columns but not according to the user's inputs

```
function makeGrid() {
let numOfRow = 0; let numOfCol = 0;

$('#submit').on('click', function() {

    numOfRow = $('#height').val();
    numOfCol = $('#width').val();

    for (var i = 1; i <= numOfRow; i++) {
        let row = $('.grid-canvas').append('<tr>');
        for (col = 1; col <= numOfCol; col++) {
            $('tr').append('<td></td>');
        }
    }
}); 
}

makeGrid();
```

Assuming a user inputs numOfRow = 2 and numOfCol = 2, I should have a table like this

```
<tbody class="grid-canvas">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Problem is my code seems to be adding extra  but I haven't been able to figure it out. This is the result of my code

```
<tbody class="grid-canvas">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

How do I fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing your code from:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {

numOfRow = $('#height').val();
numOfCol = $('#width').val();

for (var i = 1; i <= numOfRow; i++) {
    let row = $('.grid-canvas').append('<tr>');
    for (col = 1; col <= numOfCol; col++) {
        $('tr').append('<td></td>');
    }
}
});
```

into this

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {

numOfRow = $('#height').val();
numOfCol = $('#width').val();
var body = $('.grid-canvas');
for (var i = 1; i <= numOfRow; i++) {
  let row = $('<tr></tr>');
  for (col = 1; col <= numOfCol; col++) {
    row.append('<td></td>');
  }
  body.append(row);
}
});
```

what i have done in the above code is created a separate object for the table's body and then once my rows are created with the columns, I append them back to the table object.

Comment: This answer was helpful to learn that adding tables, tr, td dynamically with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Pure javascript code is here

```js
function f(x, y) {
  var rows = x,
    rowButtonNumber = y;

  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  table.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for (var j = 0; j < rowButtonNumber; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      var btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.innerHTML = "btn " + (i + 1);
      btn.id = "btn-" + i;
      btn.onclick = function() {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
      };
      td.appendChild(btn);
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
}

function go() {
  var row = document.getElementById("row").value;
  var col = document.getElementById("col").value;
  f(row, col);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    td {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    button {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  Rows
  <input id="row" type="number" placeholder="Rows" />
  <br> Columns
  <input id="col" type="number" placeholder="Columns" />
  <button onclick="go()">Go</button>

  <table id="myTable" cellspacing="50">

  </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

It does not seem you are using the `row` variable. I would suggest appending newly created `td` to `row` instead of `$('tr')`.

Comment: Appending  `<td>` to row will not create  `<tr>` so that wouldn't create the table structure. How do you mean I'm not using the row variable?

Comment: I meant using `row.append(....)` instead of `$('tr').append` - just as vikscool answered you above.